# Files not installing for Django/Python web app

Tags: python, django, heroku, pipenv

I'm trying to open a web app locally on my laptop and the files aren't installing. I tried these two methods of installing the files:

```
    $ pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
    $ pipenv install -r ./requirements.txt
```

But in both ways, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing scipy==1.1.0
...
ERROR: Couldn't install package: psycopg2
...
 Package installation failed...
```

So I then manually installed the files on the command line.
But, when I do `$python3 manage.py runserver` then I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fbb65b6b790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhanush/.local/share/virtualenvs/sisu-test-release-uLyEUBTr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dhanush/.local/share/virtualenvs/sisu-test-release-uLyEUBTr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/dhanush/.local/share/virtualenvs/sisu-test-release-uLyEUBTr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/Users/dhanush/.local/share/virtualenvs/sisu-test-release-uLyEUBTr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/dhanush/.local/share/virtualenvs/sisu-test-release-uLyEUBTr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
...
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I've spent all day trying to get this web app running. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12977 did you try these workarounds?

Comment: tried it, still giving me an error :(